# linux server running slow if mysql (mariadb) service is running

Tags: mysql, linux, performance

I have setup an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on i7-2600 box with 24G ram. I use mariadb-10.0.11 to replace mysql for more performance. And I use matmul.c (c) 2009, Rajorshi Biswas to test the system performance.The result is unusual, there is no access to mysql (mariab) server and the matnul.c result is

```
root@mercury:~/openmp/testopenmp# ./matmul.gcc
Enter dimension ('N' for 'NxN' matrix) (100-2000): 2000
Populating array with random values...
Completed array init.
Crunching without OMP... took 55.691565 seconds.
Crunching with OMP... took 15.113471 seconds.
```

but if i turn mysql mariadb off by services mysql stop the speed is much faster.

```
root@mercury:~/openmp/testopenmp# ./matmul.gcc
Enter dimension ('N' for 'NxN' matrix) (100-2000): 2000
Populating array with random values...
Completed array init.
Crunching without OMP... took 26.777045 seconds.
Crunching with OMP... took 3.646939 seconds
```

The single thread only use half time and the OMP version even faster.

Is there is configuration issues to make such performance slow down issue or it just natural??

Remark, there is no connection to mysql during the test.

I enclosed the matural.c and mysql.cnf

(the use of matural.c is just an example, all other program run slower 50% when mysql is running.)

```
/*
 * Sample program to test runtime of simple matrix multiply
 * with and without OpenMP on gcc-4.3.3-tdm1 (mingw)
 *
 * (c) 2009, Rajorshi Biswas
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <omp.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int n;
    double temp;
    double start, end, run;

    printf("Enter dimension ('N' for 'NxN' matrix) (100-2000): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    assert( n >= 100 && n <= 2000 );

    int **arr1 = malloc( sizeof(int*) * n);
    int **arr2 = malloc( sizeof(int*) * n);
    int **arr3 = malloc( sizeof(int*) * n);

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        arr1[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * n );
        arr2[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * n );
        arr3[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * n );
    }

    printf("Populating array with random values...\n");
    srand( time(NULL) );

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        for(j=0; j<n; ++j) {
            arr1[i][j] = (rand() % n);
            arr2[i][j] = (rand() % n);
        }
    }

    printf("Completed array init.\n");
    printf("Crunching without OMP...");
    fflush(stdout);
    start = omp_get_wtime();

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        for(j=0; j<n; ++j) {
            temp = 0;
            for(k=0; k<n; ++k) {
                temp += arr1[i][k] * arr2[k][j];
            }
            arr3[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }

    end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf(" took %f seconds.\n", end-start);
    printf("Crunching with OMP...");
    fflush(stdout);
    start = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k, temp)
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        for(j=0; j<n; ++j) {
            temp = 0;
            for(k=0; k<n; ++k) {
                temp += arr1[i][k] * arr2[k][j];
            }
            arr3[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }


    end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf(" took %f seconds.\n", end-start);

    return 0;
}
```

And my.cnf

```
root@mercury:~/openmp/testopenmp# cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
#port           = 3306
socket          = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#character_set_server = utf8

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 19

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#

#
# * IMPORTANT
#   If you make changes to these settings and your system uses apparmor, you may
#   also need to also adjust /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld.
#
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
character_set_server = utf8
init_connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'


user            = mysql
socket          = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#port           = 3306
basedir         = /usr/local/mysql
datadir         = /usr/local/mysql/data
tmpdir          = /tmp
#log            = /var/log/mysql.log
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql.log
general_log      = 1
# skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 1M
net_buffer_length = 16K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all.
# skip-networking

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
server-id       = 1

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = /srv/mysql
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /srv/mysql
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout


#!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/



root@mercury:/etc/mysql/conf.d# cat *
#
# The MySQL 5.6 database server configuration file.
#
# This custom MySQL 5.6 specific configuration file
# adds on top of the existing default my.cnf file at
# - /etc/mysql/my.cnf.
#
# Please add any extra MySQL 5.6 options in this file
# for sake of clarity.
#
# You may uncomment any existing option to enable it
#
# sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
[mysqld_safe]
syslog
root@mercury:/etc/mysql/conf.d#
```

Comment: Why exactly is this question tagged `php`?

Comment: Is your tables innoDB? without proper configuration you will not achieve performance

Comment: @Antonis I do not use innoDB but only MyISAM and a few use MEMORY table but they are small size.

Comment: Please share Key_reads and Key_read_requests from SHOW GLOBAL STATUS

Comment: @Antonis Thanks for your advice, I checked Key_reads and Key_read_requests, it gives some numbers as

Key_blocks_not_flushed 0
Key_blocks_unused 13357
Key_blocks_used
39
Key_blocks_warm 0
Key_read_requests 7326
Key_reads 31
Key_write_requests 783
Key_writes 783

Comment: Your hit ratio is low 31/7326 try to resize key_buffer_size

Comment: @Antonis I tried to reduce key_buffer_size to 1M but it doesn't help at all. What else I can do?

Comment: I was thinking to increase it

Comment: @Antonis I increased it to 64M and restart the service with no improvement. In fact, there is no loading or access to mysql server when i do the performance test.

Comment: Did you rule out basic stuff like corrupt drives or files?

Comment: @ToBe The system is installed in SSD drive and I did use {smartmontools} to check drives with no error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not solved, so I enclosed the processes list before and after mysql service running. Sorry to put as an answer as the question is over 300000 chars.

The processes list when mysql service is running

```
root@mercury:~# ps -elf
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S root         1     0  0  80   0 -  8348 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/init
1 S root         2     0  0  80   0 -     0 kthrea 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
1 S root         3     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
1 S root         4     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0]
1 S root         5     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
1 S root         6     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:0]
1 S root         7     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_gp 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_sched]
1 S root         8     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/0]
1 S root         9     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/1]
1 S root        10     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/2]
1 S root        11     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/3]
1 S root        12     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/4]
1 S root        13     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/5]
1 S root        14     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/6]
1 S root        15     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/7]
1 S root        16     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_gp 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
1 S root        17     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/0]
1 S root        18     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/1]
1 S root        19     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/2]
1 S root        20     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/3]
1 S root        21     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/4]
1 S root        22     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/5]
1 S root        23     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/6]
1 S root        24     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/7]
1 S root        25     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
5 S root        26     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
5 S root        27     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/1]
1 S root        28     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
1 S root        29     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
1 S root        30     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0]
1 S root        31     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H]
5 S root        32     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/2]
1 S root        33     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/2]
1 S root        34     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
1 S root        35     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0]
1 S root        36     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0H]
5 S root        37     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/3]
1 S root        38     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/3]
1 S root        39     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
1 S root        40     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0]
1 S root        41     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0H]
5 S root        42     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/4]
1 S root        43     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/4]
1 S root        44     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/4]
1 S root        45     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/4:0]
1 S root        46     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/4:0H]
5 S root        47     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/5]
1 S root        48     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/5]
1 S root        49     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/5]
1 S root        50     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/5:0]
1 S root        51     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/5:0H]
5 S root        52     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/6]
1 S root        53     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/6]
1 S root        54     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/6]
1 S root        55     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/6:0]
1 S root        56     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/6:0H]
5 S root        57     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/7]
1 S root        58     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/7]
1 S root        59     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/7]
1 S root        60     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/7:0]
1 S root        61     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/7:0H]
1 S root        62     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]
5 S root        63     2  0  80   0 -     0 devtmp 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
1 S root        64     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
1 S root        65     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [writeback]
1 S root        66     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd]
1 S root        67     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
1 S root        68     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u17:0]
1 S root        69     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
1 S root        70     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ata_sff]
1 S root        71     2  0  80   0 -     0 hub_th 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [khubd]
1 S root        72     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [md]
1 S root        73     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [devfreq_wq]
1 S root        74     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:1]
1 S root        75     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:1]
1 S root        79     2  0  80   0 -     0 watchd 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
1 S root        80     2  0  80   0 -     0 kswapd 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
1 S root        81     2  0  85   5 -     0 ksm_sc 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
1 S root        82     2  0  99  19 -     0 khugep 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [khugepaged]
1 S root        83     2  0  80   0 -     0 fsnoti 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [fsnotify_mark]
1 S root        84     2  0  80   0 -     0 ecrypt 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
1 S root        85     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [crypto]
1 S root        97     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]
1 S root        98     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/6:1]
1 S root        99     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1]
1 S root       118     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [deferwq]
1 S root       119     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [charger_manager]
1 S root       128     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/5:1]
1 S root       179     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kpsmoused]
1 S root       180     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:2]
1 S root       181     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1]
1 S root       182     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_0]
1 S root       183     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_1]
1 S root       184     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_2]
1 S root       185     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_3]
1 S root       186     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_4]
1 S root       187     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_5]
1 S root       188     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:2]
1 S root       189     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:3]
1 S root       190     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:4]
1 S root       191     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:5]
1 S root       192     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:6]
1 S root       193     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:7]
1 S root       194     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_6]
1 S root       195     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_7]
1 S root       196     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:8]
1 S root       197     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:9]
1 S root       198     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:1]
1 S root       199     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/7:1]
1 S root       201     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:10]
1 S root       206     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
1 S root       214     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/4:1]
1 S root       215     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-worker-1]
1 S root       216     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-genwork-1]
1 S root       217     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-submit-1]
1 S root       218     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-delalloc-]
1 S root       219     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-fixup-1]
1 S root       220     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-1]
1 S root       221     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
1 S root       222     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-rmw-1]
1 S root       223     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-rai]
1 S root       224     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
1 S root       225     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-wri]
1 S root       226     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-freespace]
1 S root       227     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-delayed-m]
1 S root       228     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-cache-1]
1 S root       229     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-readahead]
1 S root       230     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-flush_del]
1 S root       231     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-qgroup-re]
1 S root       232     2  0  80   0 -     0 cleane 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-cleaner]
1 S root       233     2  0  80   0 -     0 transa 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-transacti]
1 S root       402     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u17:1]
1 S root       423     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
1 S root       437     2  0  80   0 -     0 kjourn 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
1 S root       438     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
1 S root       442     2  0  80   0 -     0 kjourn 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/sda5-8]
1 S root       443     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
1 S root       447     2  0  80   0 -     0 kjourn 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/sda6-8]
1 S root       448     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
1 S root       469     1  0  80   0 -  5001 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
5 S root       478     1  0  80   0 - 12888 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
5 S message+   488     1  0  80   0 -  9810 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
1 S root       556     2  0   9   - -     0 irq_th 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [irq/61-mei_me]
4 S root       557     1  0  80   0 - 10863 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
5 S syslog     599     1  0  80   0 - 63962 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
1 S root       624     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [led_workqueue]
1 S root       678     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-2]
1 S root       700     1  0  80   0 -  3986 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
1 S root       717     1  0  80   0 -  3815 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
4 S root      1008     1  0  80   0 -  3955 n_tty_ 21:07 tty4     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
4 S root      1015     1  0  80   0 -  3955 n_tty_ 21:07 tty2     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
4 S root      1016     1  0  80   0 -  3955 n_tty_ 21:07 tty3     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
1 S root      1033     1  0  80   0 -  1092 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socke
4 S root      1034     1  0  80   0 - 15342 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
1 S root      1036     1  0  80   0 -  5914 hrtime 21:07 ?        00:00:00 cron
1 S daemon    1038     1  0  80   0 -  4785 hrtime 21:07 ?        00:00:00 atd
5 S root      1078     1  0  80   0 -  4816 hrtime 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
1 S root      1278     1  0  80   0 -  1111 wait   21:07 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/ipsec/_plutorun --debug  --uniqu
0 S root      1279     1  0  80   0 -  1085 pipe_w 21:07 ?        00:00:00 logger -s -p daemon.error -t ipsec__plutorun
1 S root      1280  1278  0  80   0 -  1111 wait   21:07 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/ipsec/_plutorun --debug  --uniqu
0 S root      1282  1278  0  80   0 -  1111 pipe_w 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/ipsec/_plutoload --wait no --pos
4 S root      1285  1280  0  80   0 - 23516 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/ipsec/pluto --nofork --secretsfile /etc/
1 S root      1389  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  0
1 S root      1390  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  1
1 S root      1392  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  2
1 S root      1393  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  3
1 S root      1394  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  4
1 S root      1395  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  5
1 S root      1396  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  6
0 S root      1532  1285  0  80   0 -  1589 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 _pluto_adns
4 S root      1552     1  0  80   0 -  1111 wait   21:07 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadi
4 S mysql     1702  1552  0  99  19 - 174953 poll_s 21:07 ?       00:00:00 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/
5 S root      1744     1  0  80   0 -  6226 sigsus 21:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
5 S www-data  1746  1744  0  80   0 -  6359 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data  1747  1744  0  80   0 -  6359 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data  1748  1744  0  80   0 -  6359 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data  1749  1744  0  80   0 -  6359 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S root      1761     1  0  80   0 - 108450 ep_pol 21:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/php/etc/php-f
5 S www-data  1762  1761  0  80   0 - 108450 skb_re 21:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: pool default
5 S www-data  1763  1761  0  80   0 - 108450 skb_re 21:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: pool default
4 S root      1860     1  0  80   0 -  6336 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master
4 S postfix   1869  1860  0  80   0 -  6852 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t unix -u -c
4 S postfix   1870  1860  0  80   0 -  6865 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
1 S root      1878     1  0  80   0 -  2671 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/pptpd
1 S root      1894     1  0  80   0 -  1110 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/xl2tpd
4 S root      1948     1  0  80   0 -  3955 n_tty_ 21:07 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
4 S root      1961  1034  0  80   0 - 26409 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/0
1 S root      1963     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-wri]
1 S root      1965     2  0  80   0 -     0 kaudit 21:08 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]
4 S root      2012  1961  0  80   0 -  5848 wait   21:08 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
0 R root      2028  2012  0  80   0 -  4612 -      21:08 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -elf
```

Answer (score 0):

The processes list after mysql service stopped.

```
root@mercury:~# service mysql stop
Shutting down MySQL.. SUCCESS!
root@mercury:~# ps -elf
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S root         1     0  0  80   0 -  8348 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/init
1 S root         2     0  0  80   0 -     0 kthrea 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
1 S root         3     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
1 S root         5     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
1 S root         6     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:0]
1 S root         7     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_gp 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_sched]
1 S root         8     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/0]
1 S root         9     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/1]
1 S root        10     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/2]
1 S root        11     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/3]
1 S root        12     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/4]
1 S root        13     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/5]
1 S root        14     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/6]
1 S root        15     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/7]
1 S root        16     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_gp 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
1 S root        17     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/0]
1 S root        18     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/1]
1 S root        19     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/2]
1 S root        20     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/3]
1 S root        21     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/4]
1 S root        22     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/5]
1 S root        23     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/6]
1 S root        24     2  0  80   0 -     0 rcu_no 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [rcuob/7]
1 S root        25     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
5 S root        26     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
5 S root        27     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/1]
1 S root        28     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
1 S root        29     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
1 S root        30     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0]
1 S root        31     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H]
5 S root        32     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/2]
1 S root        33     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/2]
1 S root        34     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
1 S root        35     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0]
1 S root        36     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0H]
5 S root        37     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/3]
1 S root        38     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/3]
1 S root        39     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
1 S root        40     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0]
1 S root        41     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0H]
5 S root        42     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/4]
1 S root        43     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/4]
1 S root        44     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/4]
1 S root        45     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/4:0]
1 S root        46     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/4:0H]
5 S root        47     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/5]
1 S root        48     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/5]
1 S root        49     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/5]
1 S root        50     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/5:0]
1 S root        51     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/5:0H]
5 S root        52     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/6]
1 S root        53     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/6]
1 S root        54     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/6]
1 S root        55     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/6:0]
1 S root        56     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/6:0H]
5 S root        57     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/7]
1 S root        58     2  0 -40   - -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [migration/7]
1 S root        59     2  0  80   0 -     0 smpboo 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/7]
1 S root        60     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/7:0]
1 S root        61     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/7:0H]
1 S root        62     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]
5 S root        63     2  0  80   0 -     0 devtmp 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
1 S root        64     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
1 S root        65     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [writeback]
1 S root        66     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd]
1 S root        67     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
1 S root        68     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u17:0]
1 S root        69     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
1 S root        70     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ata_sff]
1 S root        71     2  0  80   0 -     0 hub_th 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [khubd]
1 S root        72     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [md]
1 S root        73     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [devfreq_wq]
1 S root        74     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:1]
1 S root        79     2  0  80   0 -     0 watchd 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
1 S root        80     2  0  80   0 -     0 kswapd 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
1 S root        81     2  0  85   5 -     0 ksm_sc 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
1 S root        82     2  0  99  19 -     0 khugep 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [khugepaged]
1 S root        83     2  0  80   0 -     0 fsnoti 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [fsnotify_mark]
1 S root        84     2  0  80   0 -     0 ecrypt 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
1 S root        85     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [crypto]
1 S root        97     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]
1 S root        98     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/6:1]
1 S root        99     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1]
1 S root       118     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [deferwq]
1 S root       119     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [charger_manager]
1 S root       128     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/5:1]
1 S root       179     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kpsmoused]
1 S root       180     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:2]
1 S root       181     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1]
1 S root       182     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_0]
1 S root       183     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_1]
1 S root       184     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_2]
1 S root       185     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_3]
1 S root       186     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_4]
1 S root       187     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_5]
1 S root       194     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_6]
1 S root       195     2  0  80   0 -     0 scsi_e 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_7]
1 S root       197     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u16:9]
1 S root       198     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:1]
1 S root       199     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/7:1]
1 S root       206     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
1 S root       214     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/4:1]
1 S root       215     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-worker-1]
1 S root       216     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-genwork-1]
1 S root       217     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-submit-1]
1 S root       218     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-delalloc-]
1 S root       219     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-fixup-1]
1 S root       220     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-1]
1 S root       221     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
1 S root       222     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-rmw-1]
1 S root       223     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-rai]
1 S root       224     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
1 S root       226     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-freespace]
1 S root       227     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-delayed-m]
1 S root       228     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-cache-1]
1 S root       229     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-readahead]
1 S root       230     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-flush_del]
1 S root       231     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-qgroup-re]
1 S root       232     2  0  80   0 -     0 cleane 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-cleaner]
1 S root       233     2  0  80   0 -     0 transa 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-transacti]
1 S root       402     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u17:1]
1 S root       437     2  0  80   0 -     0 kjourn 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
1 S root       438     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
1 S root       442     2  0  80   0 -     0 kjourn 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/sda5-8]
1 S root       443     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
1 S root       447     2  0  80   0 -     0 kjourn 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/sda6-8]
1 S root       448     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
1 S root       469     1  0  80   0 -  5001 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
5 S root       478     1  0  80   0 - 12888 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
5 S message+   488     1  0  80   0 -  9810 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
1 S root       556     2  0   9   - -     0 irq_th 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [irq/61-mei_me]
4 S root       557     1  0  80   0 - 10863 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
5 S syslog     599     1  0  80   0 - 63962 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
1 S root       624     2  0  60 -20 -     0 rescue 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [led_workqueue]
1 S root       700     1  0  80   0 -  3986 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
1 S root       717     1  0  80   0 -  3815 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
4 S root      1008     1  0  80   0 -  3955 n_tty_ 21:07 tty4     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
4 S root      1015     1  0  80   0 -  3955 n_tty_ 21:07 tty2     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
4 S root      1016     1  0  80   0 -  3955 n_tty_ 21:07 tty3     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
1 S root      1033     1  0  80   0 -  1092 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socke
4 S root      1034     1  0  80   0 - 15342 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
1 S root      1036     1  0  80   0 -  5914 hrtime 21:07 ?        00:00:00 cron
1 S daemon    1038     1  0  80   0 -  4785 hrtime 21:07 ?        00:00:00 atd
5 S root      1078     1  0  80   0 -  4816 hrtime 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
1 S root      1278     1  0  80   0 -  1111 wait   21:07 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/ipsec/_plutorun --debug  --uniqu
0 S root      1279     1  0  80   0 -  1085 pipe_w 21:07 ?        00:00:00 logger -s -p daemon.error -t ipsec__plutorun
1 S root      1280  1278  0  80   0 -  1111 wait   21:07 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/ipsec/_plutorun --debug  --uniqu
0 S root      1282  1278  0  80   0 -  1111 pipe_w 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/ipsec/_plutoload --wait no --pos
4 S root      1285  1280  0  80   0 - 23516 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/ipsec/pluto --nofork --secretsfile /etc/
1 S root      1389  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  0
1 S root      1390  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  1
1 S root      1392  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  2
1 S root      1393  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  3
1 S root      1394  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  4
1 S root      1395  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  5
1 S root      1396  1285  0  90  10 - 23518 unix_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pluto helper  #  6
0 S root      1532  1285  0  80   0 -  1589 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 _pluto_adns
5 S root      1744     1  0  80   0 -  6226 sigsus 21:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
5 S www-data  1746  1744  0  80   0 -  6359 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data  1747  1744  0  80   0 -  6359 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data  1748  1744  0  80   0 -  6359 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data  1749  1744  0  80   0 -  6359 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S root      1761     1  0  80   0 - 108450 ep_pol 21:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/php/etc/php-f
5 S www-data  1762  1761  0  80   0 - 108450 skb_re 21:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: pool default
5 S www-data  1763  1761  0  80   0 - 108450 skb_re 21:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: pool default
4 S root      1860     1  0  80   0 -  6336 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master
4 S postfix   1869  1860  0  80   0 -  6852 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t unix -u -c
4 S postfix   1870  1860  0  80   0 -  6865 ep_pol 21:07 ?        00:00:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
1 S root      1878     1  0  80   0 -  2671 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/pptpd
1 S root      1894     1  0  80   0 -  1110 poll_s 21:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/xl2tpd
4 S root      1948     1  0  80   0 -  3955 n_tty_ 21:07 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
4 S root      1961  1034  0  80   0 - 26409 -      21:07 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/0
1 S root      1963     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:07 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-wri]
1 S root      1965     2  0  80   0 -     0 kaudit 21:08 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]
4 S root      2012  1961  0  80   0 -  5863 wait   21:08 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
1 S root      2035     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 21:13 ?        00:00:00 [btrfs-endio-2]
0 R root      2064  2012  0  80   0 -  4612 -      21:14 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -elf
```